# Should we have extension by definitions in FITCH proof system?

Tags: first-order-logic

A very elegant feature of FITCH FOL system is that it has a hierarchical structure: whenever necessary, a sub-proof can be started by introducing a constant symbol together with an axiom introduced for that symbol, and there is a way to go back to its parent-level proof. For example, given the statement there exists some $x$ such that $P\left(x\right)$, we may start a sub-proof by introducing $P\left(x_{0}\right)$. If we get a conclusion not about $x_{0}$, that conclusion can be moved to the upper-level proof following the existential statement. This feature, in my understanding, is a way to extend axioms.

Recently, I thought about the feature, namely, extension by definitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions. Basically, it says whenever we have a statement: for all $x$, there exists a unique $y$ such that $P\left(x,y\right)$, we may extend the original system by adding one axiom about a new function symbol $F$: for any $x$, $P\left(x, F\left(x\right)\right)$ without introducing new theorems in the original system. I tried to relate this feature to FITCH. Can we add a new rule to FITCH as follows: whenever we see a statement that for any $x$, $P\left(x, F\left(x\right)\right)$, we are allowed to similarly start a sub-proof by introducing the symbol $F$ and a new axiom for that sub-proof. The way to get back to upper-level is the same: we need to get rid of $F$ using the rules specified in the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions.

At least in my book, I didn't see such rules of extension by definition specified for the FITCH system. However, I indeed consider this feature should be a natural extension of FITCH for unique existence. This means any time we introduce a new definition, we are going one level deeper in FITCH. As we have a rule to go back to one level up, we can always see a definition as temporary. This is very much like programming: we are allowed to define variables in a local scope and get rid of the definition once the scope is complete. Can some expert on FITCH help clarify?

Comment: Are you referring to a specific computer implementation of the proof system? If not, the "technique" is a FOL result: we prove the existence and uniqueness of the "object" O and the Extension-by-def meta-theorem allow us to move to a "larger" system with the new symbol $O$ ruled by its definitional axiom.

Comment: When you say 'axiom' do you mean 'assumption'?